# Should Exceptions be placed in a separate package?

Tags: java, exception

I am taking on a project where all the Exceptions have been placed in a separate package `com.myco.myproj.exceptions`.

Is this good practice?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

I would expect the exceptions for a package to exist within that package. e.g.

```
com.oopsconsultancy.models.pricing
```

would contain pricing models and related exceptions. Anything else seems a bit counter-intuitive.

Comment: +1: Exception is co-located with the things that cause the Exception.

Answer (score 51):

It is a bad practice.

It is a coincidental grouping. Packages should be coherent. Don't group exceptions, interfaces, enum, abstract classes, etc., into their own package. Group related concepts instead.

Answer (score 3):

In my view, the question is about the type of cohesion you want your filesystem to emphasize.

Grouping exceptions with exceptions, services with services, constant with constants and so on is called **Logical Cohesion**, which is generally considered a weak type of cohesion.

Grouping things based on the fact that they contribute to a single and well-defined task, such as `usermanagement`, or `authentication` is called **Functional Cohesion** and is considered stronger and preferable to logical cohesion. In this model, exceptions related to user management would go to the usermanagement package, together with other classes dedicated to user management. In this model, we group things based on their functional role, not based on the "kind" of entity they are - such as "Exceptions".

So yes, I also double the answer of Tom Hawtin. This is no good practice.

To read more about cohesion, some sources are [geeksforgeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/software-engineering-coupling-and-cohesion/) and [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohesion_(computer_science)). I am sure you can find tones of other sources too, in case you want to investigate the concept further.

Answer (score 2):

It would be a **bad practice** and will lead to unnecessary inter package dependencies. A custom exception class should always be defined in the same package as the classes which are capable of throwing it. You should try to minimize creating custom exception which are used all over the application, for that use **Exception**. Custom exception, as the name implies is a customized one, and should be focused on a specific section. This should be the same for custom utility classes.

Package should be able to present a single unit of functionality. Refer [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/packages.html) for an example. *A Custom Exception, which is gonna thrown out of it, is a part of that unit of functionality, and should be in the same package*.

ex:

```
// Below should be in a single package
interface Draggable{}
abstract class Graphic{}
class Circle extends Graphic implements Draggable{}
class Box extends Graphic implements Draggable{}
final class GraphicValidator {// utility  class}
// don't put below in a separate 'exceptions' package, 
// who's gonna use it anyway other than the components in this package ?
class GraphicRenderingException extends Exception{}
```

Comment: It is not appropriate to throw Exception or RuntimeException unless you are a java.* committer.

Comment: @TimP can you please elaborate ?