# Java Custom exceptions: Package convention?

Tags: java, exception

When creating a `custom exception class` (e.g. a custom runtime exception), is there a specific convention for where within the `folder/package` structure to create it?

Should all the custom exception classes be within the *same* package?

Comment: same package? No. But they all must extend Throwable or any of its subclass.

Comment: No, you should not create separate package. See "package by  feature":http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=205

Comment: Check how Java´s Exceptions are organized and use the same approach.

Comment: @rajuGT RuntimeException, you mean. There's also a java.lang.Runtime, so your choice of shorthand could be confusing.

Comment: In general there's no "right way".  Most folks put the exception classes into packages where they are logically relevant, and maintain a loose exception per concern kind of association.   I tend to take this a step further and make exceptions inner classes of the classes that throw them, although people have mixed opinions on this - I've been told "OMG NO HATE STOP BAD"  and "Oh, how clever/clean"...

Comment: So it doesn't really matter where the custom exception class is created?

Comment: Can't understand they must all extend @rajuGT RuntimeException??, why?? I would say Throwable or sub class...

Comment: @yshavit and Petter I edited my comment. It was mistake. I meant Throwable, superclass of Exception class.

Comment: The convention is _definitely_ to extend from Exception (or one of its subclasses, including RuntimeException) unless you have a very good reason to. You generally shouldn't extend from anywhere else in the Throwable hierarchy.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should Exceptions be placed in a separate package?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/825281/should-exceptions-be-placed-in-a-separate-package)

Answer (score 25):

An exception class should always be defined in the same package as the classes which are capable of throwing it.  Never create a separate package just to hold exceptions.

In general, a package should encapsulate a single major unit of functionality.  Exceptions are part of that functionality.

Subpackages should only be created to limit access to classes and/or methods.  This is done by creating "package access" classes and/or methods:  they are neither public, nor protected, nor private.  Having no access modifier means they are visible only to classes in the same package.  If you don't have any such classes or methods, you probably shouldn't be making a subpackage.

Subpackages should *not* be created for:

- grouping a few classes that happen to have some things in common.  (Notice there's no java.text.format or java.net.socket or javax.swing.button package in Java SE.)
- breaking up a package because it seems to have too many classes in it.  (There's nothing wrong with having fifty classes in one package.)

Comment: "Subpackages should not be created for..." Says who? Both examples you list are valid when to primary mode for decomposition is functional. Typically organizing by technical concerns is lower in the package hierarchy.

Comment: @btiernay Says Java SE.  [Here’s the list of all packages.](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/allpackages-index.html)  I don’t see any exception-only subpackages.

Comment: @VGR `Subpackages should only be created to limit access to classes and/or methods` - so you want to emphasize that the _only_ function of the package is encapsulation? You completely deny package as the mean to _structure_ your code?

Comment: @Max Yes, exactly.  Exceptions are not part of structure.  Separate packages are for major units of functionality.

Comment: @VGR, well, i understand you have this opinion, what is unclear for me is why you don't consider _package (as language tool) having different purpose at different hierarchical level_. I mean smth like - on the top - packages are by feature (best desigin choice out of 3-4 choices we have), but - at lower levels - package can have a structural or functional decomposition role.

Comment: @Max It’s an “opinion” shared by Java SE.  If you’re thinking that subpackages as a form of organization is a way to be “self documenting,” I would argue that such an approach is better solved by writing javadoc.

Comment: @VGR. You have strong statement `Subpackages should only be created to limit access to classes and/or methods`. Well, we have package as the language tool. It may be applied for: delimiting features, units of release (cohesive units), pure encapsulation, or - _just for code structuring_ + i can name 5 use cases more. Usually people start with packages as tool for delimiting features (at top level). I'd like to understand why _at lower levels (especially in big project) we can't start to gradually use other use cases of package as the tool_? (Exceptions are usual code, so no specifics here)

Comment: @Max If your argument is “the language allows it, so why shouldn’t I do it,” I can name a lot of poor practices that the compiler allows.  I don’t know how packages are used to delimit features, but encapsulation would be a good use of a subpackage that I think my description covers.  Code structuring is not a good usage, as it splinters the API and makes it harder to use while providing no benefit.  A large package functions just fine without being split up, and the javadoc is easier to read than searching multiple packages would be.

Comment: @VGR `the language allows it,so why shouldn’t I do it` = your interpretation. I say: we have tool+ use some principles. `packages are used to delimit features` = i mean top level of packages as division by features (say, app.billing, app.claims, etc). encapsulation = i agree 100%, it's one of superb use cases of packages. What you keep ignoring in my question is: _application of different use cases of packages at different levels of large project_ (why that splinters API?) `versus` your single radical principle `Subpackages should only be created to limit access to classes and/or methods`.

Comment: @VGR `...while providing no benefit` - the benefit is in the name of one of the package use cases - namely - code structuring in large code base.