# Spring Boot project structure with Authentication

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-security

I am learning Spring boot and its modules, but I want avoid to learning bad practices. So can you tell me what project structure is usually using for that?

I am using this structure:

```
com
 +- example
     +- myproject
         +- Application.java
         |
         +- config
         |   +- CustomSecurityConfig.java (extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter)
         |
         +- domain
         |   +- Customer.java
         |
         +- repository
         |   +- CustomerRepository.java
         |    
         +- service
         |   +- CustomerService.java
         |
         +- web
             +- CustomerController.java
```

Now I need implement JWT Authentication, so I have theese new classes:

- CustomAuthFilter.java for Security Filter Chain
- CustomUserDetailsService.java for AuthenticationManager
- CustomEntryPoint.java for handle exceptions
- CustomJwtService.java for managing jwt tokens
- CustomAuthController.java for rest endpoints like /login, /logout, /create-user, /reset-password

Can you tell me where store this classes? I have 2 ideas:

1. Create **security** folder and put it here together
2. Split files into existing folders like that: CustomAuthFilter.java -> config, CustomUserDetailsService.java -> service, CustomEntryPoint.java -> config, CustomJwtService.java -> service, CustomAuthController.java -> web

Can yo give me some advice pls? Thank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is code organization problem and independent of spring boot.

Go by business sense/ functionality of the module than the technical sense of the module. Functionality sense helps to understand the code easily if you are looking after a while.

```
+Application.java
+security/ 
+-CustomAuth
+-CustomJwtSevice
```

if functionality is scatters in multiple files then keep them in subfolder like '**security**' in above.

```
+Application.java
+security/
+-auth/
+--token/
+---JWTtokenGenerator.java
+---JWTutil.java
+--configuration/
+---SecurityConfig
+---...
+--customer/
+---customerservice.java
+---customerrepo.java
```

The above pattern works by dividing a module, into sub-module and sub-module to their sub-modules.. so on

Comment: but my project is just small one ... that project structure is recommended for bigger, right? So if I want just one module, isn't something better for my purpose?

Comment: Yes ! it is usually for large application project. Large projects -> larger segregation. Small project -> smaller segregation (less directories). but thinking process will be same.

With time, A File exploded to files -> then you need to group them into package. It is evolutionary process. You should always have the attitude to improvise. 

But the process of thinking remain same. For smaller project, you might a less number of file. I don't think you should create directory for each file. Directory means - functional group.