# spring boot fat service refactoring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, design-patterns, domain-driven-design

I have a very fat class which hold the code `business logic` of my application. The class is using other service and sometimes other service's repositories to get data needed for its actions.

The entities in my application are just POJO.

So lets assume the service is `InventoryService` and it has 200 methods that we want to split up, and it uses the Product, Tax, Customer entities, would it make more sense to transfer the `business logic` to the entities themselves to reduce the code on the service level? Or rather add more services such as ProductInventoryService, TaxInventoryService and etc.. and move some of the logic to them?

Any practical examples would be appreciated, the basic design of the app is controller >service >repository where we aim to use Entities between all layers and return DTO to the client from the controller.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> So lets assume the service is `InventoryService` and it has 200
> methods that we want to split up, and it uses the Product, Tax,
> Customer entities, would it make more sense to transfer the `business logic` to the entities themselves to reduce the code on the service
> level? Or rather add more services such as ProductInventoryService,
> TaxInventoryService and etc.. and move some of the logic to them?

You already answer to your own question here. Following the [SOLID Principles](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/solid-principles-explained-in-plain-english/) and spliting your project into [Layers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40902280/what-is-the-recommended-project-structure-for-spring-boot-rest-projects), you make your code more clear, readeable and finally more maintainable.

It is very important to have a seperation of concerns in your projects and avoid strong dependencies between your layers or your components.

- By seperating your classes into `xxxService`, `xxxController` and `xxxRepository`, you implement the **S***ingle responsability principle*.
- By organizing your classes into different layers, you adopt the *N-Tiers pattern* (at your project and package level)

I would suggest you to post this question in the [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) network.

Comment: Thanks, do you have code sample to demonstrate breaking the service to sub services?

Comment: Take a look at this example: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-petclinic

Comment: Sorry i didn't see something related to my question in the example